# Update a Vaadin Grid programmatically

Tags: java, vaadin

I am trying to create a grid using Vaadin 14 that is updated by event handlers that call the updateFieldByName method below. However, the grid is never refreshed.

What I would like to achieve is simply this:

```
    aaa 1
    bbb 2
```

updateFieldByName("aaa", "ok");

```
    aaa ok
    bbb 2
```

I've tried using grid.setItems(properties) and grid.setDataProvider(dataProvider), but the table just doesn't want to update.

```
List<Property> properties = Arrays.asList(new Property("aaa", "1"), new Property("bbb", "2"));
ListDataProvider<Property> dataProvider = DataProvider.ofCollection(properties);

Grid<Property> grid = new Grid<>(Property.class);
grid.setDataProvider(dataProvider);

private void updateFieldByName(final String name, final String value) {
    properties.stream().filter((o) -> o.getName().equals(name)).forEach((p) -> {
        p.setValue(value);
        dataProvider.refreshAll();
    });
}

public static class Property {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    public Property(final String name) {
        this(name, "-");
    }

    public Property(final String name, final String value) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + name + " = " + value + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: not sure if or why this would make a difference, but can you try the refreshAll outside of the stream?

Comment: Actually when you do not add/remove items, it should be enough to call refreshItem(item) to changed item. I would also like to ask, why you use static class for your bean?

Answer (score 0):

How you are exactly calling a `updateFieldByName` method? I've added a TextField, where I am entering a `aaa` and after `ValueChangeEvent` is called, grid is updated correctly.

This is a code I am using. (I've made a separate class for a `Property` class)

```java
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataProvider;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.ListDataProvider;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Route("gridSO")
public class GridUpdateSO extends VerticalLayout {

    List<Property> properties = Arrays.asList(new Property("aaa", "1"), new Property("bbb", "2"));
    ListDataProvider<Property> dataProvider = DataProvider.ofCollection(properties);
    public GridUpdateSO() {
        Grid<Property> grid = new Grid<>(Property.class);
        grid.setDataProvider(dataProvider);
        add(grid);
        TextField ab=new TextField("TextField", e->{
            updateFieldByName(e.getValue(),"ok");

        });
        add(ab);
    }
        private void updateFieldByName(final String name, final String value) {
            properties.stream().filter((o) -> o.getName().equals(name)).forEach((p) -> {
                p.setValue(value);
                dataProvider.refreshAll();
            });
        }
    }
```

*Property.java*

```java
public class Property {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    public Property(final String name) {
        this(name, "-");
    }

    public Property(final String name, final String value) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + name + " = " + value + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The UI is deployed in a Karaf environment. The event is received from another bundle handled by an AsyncEventBus. As a result, the problem appears to involve threading issues. I also tried using textfields to the same effect. The setValue method runs, but the UI doesn't update. When I click on a button, the UI updates despite there being no listeners present.

Comment: then I would suggest to create an isolated example and submit it to Github repo, as based on your description it seems like a bug

Comment: Or you could try to post a question to a Vaadin Forum

Comment: While I was unable to get the page working from the event handler, I was able to get around the problem using the following method as described here: https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access.html. (Store values from events in class, thread sleeps then calls ui.access(...) every second.